# Dual Booting issue

Tags: dual-boot

I dual booted my new computer build with ubuntu 12.04 and windows 8. Now my ubuntu boots up but my windows will not. It sites and invalid EFI path error. Can some help? I've tried to use a boot repair disk with no luck. It's my first build and I'm super new to ubuntu and don't know my way around much at all.

Comment: What is the output of boot-repair?